# Where can Developers get Sepolia Testnet ETH?

Tags: solidity, truffle, testnets, infura

Where can web3 developers get free Sepolia Testnet ETH to use in their development process?

Answer (score 4):

You can get 1 Sepolia Eth here for free, its the largest Sepolia Faucet available:

https://sepoliafaucet.com

Answer (score 2):

Free Sepolia Testnet Faucet that lets you claim 0.5 Sepolia ETH per day.

https://www.infura.io/faucet/sepolia

Comment: Thanks a lot for this :)